# Can't delete words from a string with replaceAll

Tags: java, android

```
if(containsAllWeather || containsAllWeather2){

            String weatherLocation = value.toString();

        if (weatherLocation != null){


                weatherLocation.replaceAll("how","")
                        .replaceAll("what","")
                        .replaceAll("weather", "")
                        .replaceAll("like", "")
                        .replaceAll(" in", "")
                        .replaceAll(" at", "")
                        .replaceAll("around", "");
        }
```

weatherLocation still gives exactly what the variable *value* includes and doesn't delete any of the words listed above.

This worked when I split weatherLocation to an array of strings, say, array of weatherLoc, and those lines of code worked for weatherLoc[1]

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the values returned by the method calls back to the String reference variable. Each time you do `replaceAll()` , it returns a **new** `String` object but your `weatherLocation` variable is still referencing to the original String.

```
  weatherLocation = weatherLocation.replaceAll("how","")
                    .replaceAll("what","")
                    .replaceAll("weather", "")
                    .replaceAll("like", "")
                    .replaceAll(" in", "")
                    .replaceAll(" at", "")
                    .replaceAll("around", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable.  You need to assign the value of all those replaceAll calls to a variable and that will be what you want.

```
weatherLocation = weatherLocation.replaceAll("how","")
                .replaceAll("what","")
                .replaceAll("weather", "")
                .replaceAll("like", "")
                .replaceAll(" in", "")
                .replaceAll(" at", "")
                .replaceAll("around", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
weatherLocation = weatherLocation.replaceAll("how","")
                        .replaceAll("what","")
                        .replaceAll("weather", "")
                        .replaceAll("like", "")
                        .replaceAll(" in", "")
                        .replaceAll(" at", "")
                        .replaceAll("around", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

`String` is `immutable`. So `String.replaceAll` returns a new `instance` of `String`. So you need to use like following

```
weatherLocation = weatherLocation.replaceAll("how","")
                .replaceAll("what","")
                .replaceAll("weather", "")
                .replaceAll("like", "")
                .replaceAll(" in", "")
                .replaceAll(" at", "")
                .replaceAll("around", "");
```