# Replace White space of String as blank in Java

Tags: java

I am trying replace all white space of below string as blank

> 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49

Desire output should be -

> 89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d49

I have tried with below code. But below code is not working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49"; 
        System.out.println(input);
        input.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("[\\s\\u00A0]+$", "");
        input.replaceAll("\\w", "")
        System.out.println(input);
    }
```

Comment: @Tunaki the problem is string immutability, but the reference to the question is incorrect. The problem exposed in the question you reference is totally different

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO On the contrary, it goes deeper in the issue, which explains it a lot better. There is always this one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553159/cant-delete-words-from-a-string-with-replaceall

Comment: You can use input = input.replaceAll("\\s+","") to fix this

Comment: @Tunaki the second question seems closer to what is asked here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**String are not modifiable.**

The method `replaceAll` doesn't change the original string, but creates a new one.

So you need to reassign the result of `replaceAll` to `input`

```
input = input.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input = input.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

should do it.